# How to perform ANOVA on the dataset?

Tags: python, data-analysis, anova

I have a house price dataset where I want to find out the significance of categorical variables with the target variable ( which is a continuous variable). For that I have considered performing ANOVA but I am confused whether I should consider each categorical variable as an individual group :

```
mod1 = ols("SalePrice ~ SaleCondition", data = data_cat).fit()
anov_table1 = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod1)

mod2 = ols("SalePrice ~ Neighborhood", data = data_cat).fit()
anov_table1 = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod2)

mod3 = ols("SalePrice ~ HouseStyle", data = data_cat).fit()
anov_table1 = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod3)

mod4 = ols("SalePrice ~ OverallQual", data = data_cat).fit()
anov_table1 = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod4)
```

or should I put all the categorical variables in a single group and then perform ANOVA:

```
mod = ols("SalePrice ~ SaleCondition + Neighborhood + HouseStyle + OverallQual", data = data_cat).fit()
anov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned a target variable and seem to be using a OLS model, I assume you're trying to perform **multiple linear regression**.

You don't need to perform ANOVA manually - virtually all implementations of linear regression models automatically calculate the p-value associated with each input variable (controlling for all other input variables).

Additionally, your OLS model needs to have all input variables in it before calling the `fit()` method. In other words, *you need to put your input variables in a single group before passing them to the model, not because you need this for ANOVA (you don't), but because you need this for the multiple linear regression itself*.

In pseudocode:

```
target_var = put_your_target_series_here
input_vars = put_all_your_input_series_here
result = ols(target_var, input_vars).fit()
```

In your case, `target_var` will likely be a *pandas Series* (= a sigle column from a pandas DataFrame).

`input_vars` can be a *pandas Series* (which means you only have one input variable - that's a **simple linear regression**) or a *pandas DataFrame* (in which case each column is interpreted as an input variable - you're performing **multiple linear regression**).

The object in the variable `result` contains the p-values for all input variables in your model - refer to the documentation of the packages you're using to check how to extract them.

However, since your input variables are categories, **you WILL have to use dummy variables**. Let's say you have this data:

```
|House | Neighborhood value|
|------|-------------------|
|01    | Good              |
|02    | Bad               |
|03    | Bad               |
|04    | Excellent         |
|05    | Good              |
```

Linear regression needs to have numbers, not categories. You *might* get away with turning these categories into numbers, like:

```
|House | Neighborhood value|
|------|-------------------|
|01    | 1                 |
|02    | 0                 |
|03    | 0                 |
|04    | 2                 |
|05    | 1                 |
```

But this implicitly teaches your model that an `Excellent` neighborhood value is worth 2 times the worth of a `Good` value - which may or may not be true! Additionally, for categories like colors, this wouldn't make any sense.

The real solution is using **dummy variables**, like:

```
|House | Has excellent value | Has good value|
|------|---------------------|---------------|
|01    | 0                   | 1             |
|02    | 0                   | 0             |
|03    | 0                   | 0             |
|04    | 1                   | 0             |
|05    | 0                   | 1             |
```

This avoids the problems I've described above.

Note that we don't need a column for `Has bad value` because we assume that a house without 0s for `Has excellent value` and `Has good value` must have a bad value.

Refer to [this link](https://psychstat3.missouristate.edu/Documents/MultiBook3/Mlt07.htm) for a more in-depth explanation on dummy variables for categorical data in multiple linear regression.